# What do 「やっと」 and 「うせにゃ」 mean?

Tags: words, expressions

I am not sure if the 「やっと」 would mean 'at last' or relate to any specific Japanese dialect. Here is sentence including the words in question.

> だから わしが特{とく}別{べつ}におねがいして **やっと** おまえたちも入{にゅう}場{じょう}することもゆるされたんだ。
>
> おとなし**うせにゃ**いかんぜ。

Answer (score 3):

やっと is a standard Japanese word. It means a desire has finally come after difficulties or long time.

The second sentence is おとなしう/せにゃ/いかん/ぜ。. This sounds a little bit old, yet I think this is not a dialect but euphonic changes.

- おとなしう → おとなしく "behave yourself"
- せにゃ → せねば "if not be"
- いかん → いけない "must not"
- ぜ → ぜ

Literally, it means "If you do not behave yourself, it is bad."

The whole translation: "Because of it, I asked them exceptionally, and finally, you are allowed to enter too. You must behave yourself."