# Meaning of (せ)にゃ and から(な)

Tags: meaning

I found the following two sentences:

あとで添削**せにゃ**。- I'll look it over later.

この世界**にゃ**魔法ってのがある**からな** - There's magic on this world.

I checked the dictionary and some of the meanings of "にゃ" includes "Having to do something" and "On", which makes sense on both of those sentences.

あとで添削せにゃ - I'll (Have to) look it up later.

この世界にゃ魔法ってのがあるからな - (On) this world there's magic.

However, **I'm not sure about the usage** of せ + にゃ on **あとで添削せにゃ**

**I'm also not sure about the meaning of からな** at the end of **この世界にゃ魔法ってのがあるからな**. I assume it's a combination of から meaning from and the sentence ending particle な which has the same meaning as ね, but I'm not sure how something along the lines of "From, isn't it" would fit on the sentence.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27891/45489 and  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94581/45489 should answer your question.

Comment: `it's a combination of から meaning from` -- The から is not "from". When から follows 活用語, it's a 接続助詞 meaning "because". ある in あるから is a 活用語. When から follows a 名詞/代名詞, it's a 格助詞 meaning "from".

Answer (score 1):

Generally called "なまり（namari)" or "dialect," "にゃ(nya)" is not a common word and may be used in very casual situations between friends.

**Please note that it may be considered rude to use it in business situations.**

"な(na)" has almost the same meaning as "にゃ," but is more formal than "にゃ".

It can be used in business situations and is not considered rude.

Comment: `"な(na)" has almost the same meaning as "にゃ," but is more formal than "にゃ". It can be used in business situations and is not considered rude.`  -- Do you mean, 「あとで添削せな」 means "I have to look it over later" and can be used in business situations?

Comment: Not all places in Japan can use that phrase, but it can be used in areas where people speak Kansai-ben (e.g., Osaka).